# Sum and organize array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Assuming i have an array of arrays:

```
[[2012-12-20, 10], [2012-12-20, 25], [2012-12-19, 10], [2012-12-20, 5]]
```

How to reorganize this array by distinct DATE summing their respective values, so i have something like this:

```
[[2012-12-20, 40], [2012-12-19, 10]]
```

## EDIT

I've tried something like this:

```
var array = [[2012-12-20, 10], [2012-12-20, 25], [2012-12-19, 10], [2012-12-20, 5]];
pastDate = '';
pastVal = '';
for(var data in array) {
    var curDate = data[0];
    var curVal = data[1];   
    // ??
    // Can't figure out how to organize each value of array organized by distinct date.
    // Sorry for any fail, I tottaly sux in arrays.
}
```

Someone?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try writing a loop ? What's the problem ?

Comment: FYI `[2012-12-20, 10] === [1980, 10]`.

Comment: You can use js objects to mimic the functionality of a hash table. Hash tables are great tools when you need distinct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

http://jsbin.com/aNeQArek/2/edit

```
var g=[['2012-12-20', 10], ['2012-12-20', 25], ['2012-12-19', 10], ['2012-12-20', 5]];

var a={};

for( var i=0;i<g.length;i++)
{
   a[g[i][0]] = (a[g[i][0]] || 0) + g[i][1] ;
}

console.log(a);
```

result : (it's object with your desired values).

`{2012-12-20: 40, 2012-12-19: 10}`

Comment: @downvoter thanks for downvoting on a working code.

Comment: THANKS! I was trying to figure out how to set a KEY to distinct dates and don't figure out about javascript objects. I've just made some changes on your code and worked like a charm! Thanks again!